# Formatting Oracle SQL column with non-standard format

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle database where a file location is stored. Unfortunately, it isn't properly formatted.

For example, the file location is `C:\images\00\45\34\34.IMG` and is stored in the database as: `00453434`.

I am able to use `CONCAT` to put `C:\images` and `.IMG` around the column, but I can't format the actual location to put `\s` in.

I've tried `to_char`, and `to_number` but it requires a specified format.

(My crappy attempt: `to_char(filename, '09"\"09"\"09"\"09'))`

Is there any way in SQL to format freely?

Comment: is the length of `00453434` fixed? i.e should all the column values be split after 2 characters?

Comment: Updated code along with tag

Comment: Yes. It is always a folder (2 digits) / folder (2 digits) / folder (2 digits) / filename (2 digits)

Answer (score 0):

One method... assuming fixed length of each segment meaning each path is 2 digits including file name.

```
select 'C:\images\'|| substr('00453434',1,2) || '\' || 
                      substr('00453434',3,2) || '\' ||
                      substr('00453434',5,2) || '\' ||
                      substr('00453434',7,2) || '.IMG' as fullPath from dual
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Since the data is a fixed length, this is the easiest solution. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If needed at multiple queries, creating a PL/SQL function can also solve your problem. This example also assumes that each path has 2 digits, but supports paths of different lengths:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_FILENAME(ID IN VARCHAR2, PREFIX IN VARCHAR2, SUFFIX IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  i PLS_INTEGER;
  r VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  r := PREFIX;
  FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(ID)/2 LOOP
    r := r || '\' || SUBSTR(ID, 2*i-1, 2);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN r || SUFFIX;
END;
/
```

The function can then be used within your standard SQL queries (or view definitions) as follows:

```
WITH TA_FILES AS (
  SELECT '12345678' AS ID FROM DUAL
)
SELECT GET_FILENAME(ID, 'C:\images', '.IMG') FROM TA_FILES
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael! I'm sure I'll find some fields that aren't a fixed length and this function will be the solution I need!